# confused with lazy loading

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I use code first to test lazy loading, models as below,

```
class Team
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Boss { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public List<Player> players { get; set; }

        public Team()
        {
            players = new List<Player>();
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Team team { get; set; }
    }
```

and context likes this,

```
class testContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Team> teamSet { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Player> playerSet { get; set; }
    }
```

I read Julia Lerman's book "Programing Entity Framework", and got confused with lazy loading. When I write the code as below,

```
using (var context = new testContext())
            {
                //context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                //var teams = from t in context.teamSet.Include(p=>p.players) select t;
                var teams = from t in context.teamSet select t;
                foreach (var v in teams)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(v.players.Count());
                }
                Console.Read();
            }
```

When foreach statement is executed, I think v.players.Count() will hit the database and return me the value, and if I disabled lazy loading, it will not hit the database and return zero to me. But no matter I enabled lazy loading or disabled lazy loading, the value always zero. Is my understanding of lazy loading wrong? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make your Player's virtuel

```
public Virtual List<Player> players { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

About lazy loading..

> In this type of loading, related entities are automatically loaded
>   from the data source when you access a navigation property. With this
>   type of loading, be aware that each navigation property that you
>   access results in a separate query executing against the data source
>   if the entity is not already in the ObjectContext.

In your case it would mean that `players` is navigation property of the `v` (TeamSet). If single `team set` is loaded then Entity Framework load also `players` for that `team set`.

Your code sample is probably more like a test as there is no `.Where` for query. If later you would get hundreds of `TeamSets` then it would cause huge amount queries against database.

Read [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/iupdateable/archive/2009/11/26/getting-started-with-entity-framework-4-ndash-lazy-loading.aspx) to understand why zero count is returned.